# Existence of maximal topologically characteristic subgroup of infinite index of pro-$p$ groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a topologically finitely generated infinite pro-$p$ group. Suppose that $G$ is not just-infinite. **Does the group $G$ always have a maximal topologically characteristic subgroup of infinite index?** If not, are there any useful sufficient conditions? I am concerned with the case when $G$ is a $p$-adic analytic group.

(An infinite profinite group $G$ is called *just-infinite* if all non-trivial closed normal subgroup of $G$ have finite index. A subgroup of $G$ is *topologically characteristic* if it is invariant under all continuous automorphisms of $G$; A subgroup of $G$ is *maximal* if it is not properly contained in another subgroup of $G$.)

Comment: No: in $\mathbf{Z}_p^2$, the only topologically characteristic subgroups are $\{0\}$ and the finite index subgroups $p^n\mathbf{Z}_p^2$. Unless you mean "maximal among top. char. subgroups of infinite index" in which case your definitions are incomplete (and in which case there is no point in excluding just-infinite pro-$p$-groups).

Comment: (By the way your definition of "maximal" is incorrect. The correct definition is that it is not properly contained in any other *proper* subgroup.)